# solving two nonlinear equations using "NLEQSLV" package

Tags: r

I am trying to solve system of nonlinear equations. the problem is that the termination code returns (3) which means that " no better solution is found". I am wondering if there are certain options that should be used to get a solution or shall I search for other package with the same objective or what?
here is the code:

```
library(nleqslv) ## solving nonlinear equations
mu.initial=c(0.04732269,0.77871236) 
R.bar=0.7801489
R2.bar=0.2877999
fun=function(z){
v=z^2  
q=numeric(length(v))
q[1]=(exp(-(v[1]^2)/(2*(v[2]))))*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^3)*factorial(3)/((factorial(1))^2*(factorial(2))* 
(2^3)))+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^5)*factorial(5)/((factorial(2))^2*(factorial(3))* 
(2^6)))+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^7)*factorial(7)/((factorial(3))^2*(factorial(4))* 
(2^9)))+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^9)*factorial(9)/((factorial(4))^2*(factorial(5))* 
(2^12)))+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^11)*factorial(11)/((factorial(5))^2*(factorial(6))* 
(2^15))))-(4*R.bar/sqrt(2*pi))
q[2]=(exp(-(v[1]^2)/(2*(v[2]))))*((0.25*(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)+ 
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)*0.5)+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6)*0.1172)+(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^8)*0.01822)+ 
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^10)*0.0021)+
(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^12)*0.0002)))+4*(((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)*(-0.0104+0.00146* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)-0.00016*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)+0.000014* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6))+
((0.5)*(v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6)*(-0.039+0.0055*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)-0.00061* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)+0.000055*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6))+
((1/8)*(v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^8)*(-0.1458+0.0205*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)-0.0023* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)+0.000212*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6))+
((1/48)*(v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^10)*(-0.5468+0.0773*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)-0.00728* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)+0.0008*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6))+
((1/384)*(v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^12)*(-2.0625+0.2932*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)-0.0332* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)+0.00309*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6))+
((1/3840)*(v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^14)*(-7.82+1.117*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^2)-0.1271* 
((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^4)+0.01186*((v[1]/sqrt(v[2]))^6))))-R2.bar
 q
 }
sd=sqrt(0.9537661)
half.k=sqrt(0.7801489)
v.start=c(half.k,sd)



ss1=nleqslv(v.start,fun,method="Broyden",global="qline",control=list(cndtol=10^-12,maxit=1000,allowSingular =TRUE))
```

Comment: Please go through [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), right now your code is a little bit hard to read.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenter. Please make this readable. The package also provides a function `testnslv` to use all the methods available in the package. But no solution can be found. So analyse your system for any errors and see if it really has a solution  and a non singular jacobian.